# Sticky navigation breaks when html height: 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar on a website that is currently working fine using this jQuery code to make it "sticky" when scrolled past:

```
offset = $('#navWrapper').offset();
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if( $(window).scrollTop() >= offset.top ) {
    $('#navWrapper').addClass('fixedNavWrapper');
    $('#topHeader').addClass('fixedNavPadding');
  } else {
    $('#navWrapper').removeClass('fixedNavWrapper');
    $('#topHeader').removeClass('fixedNavPadding');             
  }
});
```

to apply and remove this CSS:

```
.fixedNavWrapper {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:999;
}
.fixedNavPadding {
  padding-bottom:45px;
}
```

When I apply "height: 100%" to html, it stops working. I need html to have height: 100% to use a sticky footer with it.. what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `html` height to `100%`, you are no longer scrolling into the window, but inside the `html`. Therefor, this code won't work :

```
$(window).scroll();
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Try changing `window` to `$('html,body')`.

Comment: Changing $(window) to $('html,body') causes it to stop working for me :\

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a fiddle? Will be easier to help!